# Installed Module and ModuleNotFoundError in MacOs Terminal

Tags: python, anaconda, modulenotfounderror

This problem has persistently blocked me for months so I'll expose it to you.

I've installed Anaconda while learning Python and it works just fine, but sometimes I want to play around with a script without launching it : I just want to work with the macOs terminal to see results or errors in my scripts.

My problem is that I often stumble upon the `ModuleNotFoundError` when I try to import modules (keyboard, matplotlib, pandas...) although all are already installed. When I try to install them again, just in case, they always point towards the path
`/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages`.

On the other hand, using `sys.path` in Python, one of the path returned is
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages`

So the modules are installed and the computer knows where they are : how can I load them in the terminal — and can I even get them to be loaded in there ?

Many thanks for your attention, hope to hear from you!

Comment: It's always good to use "Virtual Environment". Hopefully, you will not have any issues like what you have now.

Comment: I'll dig into that and see what is coming out of it, thank you !